# How to pass a string literal to a function which takes const std::wstring&

Tags: c++

I have a function which takes `const std::wstring&` font_family, i.e.

```
Font Font::CreateFont(const std::wstring& font_family){ ... }
```

By question is how can I call that funcion by passing a string literal (e.g monospace)?

I tried

```
CreateFont("monospace");
CreateFont("std::wstring("monospace") );
```

Both does not compile. 
Any one have better idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
CreateFont(L"monospace");
```

The leading "L" directs the compiler to generate a wide (wchar_t) string.

Comment: In general, L"string literal" generates a wide-character (`wchar_t`) string literal (which is exactly what you want for `std::wstring`.)  Exactly what `wchar_t` is is platform dependent.  On Windows a `wchar_t` stores a UTF-16 code point, but on other platforms it could represent, for example, a UTF-32 code point.

Comment: Note that the platform-dependency doesn't matter for the answer. L"" is a `wchar_t[]` and `std::wstring` wants a `wchar_t*`, so this works on all systems, whether `wchar_t` is 8, 16, 32 or 42 bits.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::wstring s(L"Monospace");
CreateFont(s);
```

the ctor for wstring doesn't accept narrow characters, only wides...